# Fast transformation of BGR BufferedImage to YUV using FFMpeg

Tags: java, c++, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I wanted to transform a TYPE_3BYTE_BGR BufferedImage in Java to yuv using the sws_scale function of FFMpeg through JNI. I first extract the data of my image from the BufferedImage as

```
    byte[] imgData = ((DataBufferByte) myImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

    byte[] output = processImage(toSend,0);
```

Then I pass it to the processImage function which is a native function. The C++ side looks like this:

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_jni_JniExample_processData
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jbyteArray data, jint index)
{

    jboolean isCopy;
    uint8_t *test  = (uint8_t *)env->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(data, &isCopy);
    uint8_t *inData[1]; // RGB24 have one plane
    inData[0] = test;


SwsContext * ctx = sws_getContext(width,height,AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, (int)width, (int)width,
        AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    int lumaPlaneSize = width *height;
    uint8_t *yuv[3];

    yuv[0] = new uint8_t[lumaPlaneSize];
    yuv[1] = new uint8_t[lumaPlaneSize/4];
    yuv[2] = new uint8_t[lumaPlaneSize/4];

    int inLinesize[1] = { 3*nvEncoder->width }; // RGB stride
    int outLinesize[3] = { 3*width ,3*width ,3*width }; // YUV stride

    sws_scale(ctx, inData, inLinesize, 0, height , yuv, outLinesize);
```

However, after running the code, I get the warning: `[swscaler @ 0x7fb598659480] Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speedloss, everything crashes.`, and everything crashes on the last line. Am I doing things properly in terms of passing the correct arguments to sws_scale? (specially the strides).

**Update:**
There was a separate bug here:     `SwsContext * ctx = sws_getContext(width,height,AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, (int)width, (int)width,0,NULL,NULL,NULL)` which should be changed to:  `SwsContext * ctx = sws_getContext(width,height,AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, (int)height, (int)width,0,NULL,NULL,NULL)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem I see - wrong strides for output image:

```
yuv[0] = new uint8_t[lumaPlaneSize];
yuv[1] = new uint8_t[lumaPlaneSize/4];
yuv[2] = new uint8_t[lumaPlaneSize/4];

int inLinesize[1] = { 3*nvEncoder->width }; // RGB stride
int outLinesize[3] = { 3*width ,3*width ,3*width }; // YUV stride
//                     ^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^
```

Allocated planes are not large enough for passed strides. YUV420 uses one byte for each channel, so `3` is redundant and leads to bound violation. due rescaler skips a lot of space when goes to next line. Next, actual chroma width is a half of luma width, so if you want tight-packed luma and chroma planes without gaps at line ends use next:

```
int outLinesize[3] = { width , width / 2 , width / 2 }; // YUV stride
```

Allocation sizes remain the same.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however I still have some issues. If I adjust the strides to yuv[1] = new uint8_t[lumaPlaneSize/2]; and yuv[1] = new uint8_t[lumaPlaneSize/2]; , it seems everything goes fine with your suggested outputLinesize. Except if I write the output into a file: 
fwrite(yuv[0], 1, lumaPlaneSize, fp);
fwrite(yuv[1], 1, lumaPlaneSize/4, fp);
fwrite(yuv[2], 1, lumaPlaneSize/4, fp);

It seems that the image is scaled and incomplete. I change to fwrite(yuv[1 and 2], 1, lumaPlaneSize/2, fp); then the image is bad altogether What should I do?

Comment: What exactly incomplete image looks like?

Comment: before:
https://postimg.org/image/gr93ykns1/

after:
https://postimg.org/image/f0mg9dyvb/

Comment: I guess fifth parameter of `sws_getContext()` must be height, not width.

Comment: what a sin ... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/swscale_8c_source.html), in particular around line 321, you get that warning message if your system supports AVX2 instructions and the various pointers and sizes are not multiples of 16.  The crash is probably occurring because the arrays you pass in, `inData`, `inLineSize`, and `outLinesize`, are not the right size.  The pointer arrays need to have at least 3 elements, and the stride arrays need 4.  Somewhere in `sws_scale` it is accessing `inData[1]` which is outside the bounds of your array resulting in a bad pointer.

Comment: "The pointer arrays need to have at least 3 elements, and the stride arrays need 4 ..."  - no, these sizes are strictly defined by used pixel format and in case of YUV420 both buffer array and stride array must contain exactly 3 elements - for Y, Cr, Cb planes each one.